# Center of the flange 13 1/2" not 10" or 12" what do I do?

Tags: toilet

I just bought toilet to replace old and it is in my moblehome (hasn't been moved ever, is secured to ground) but the center of the hole where toilet was sitting is 13 1/2", is this going to work?

Comment: 13 1/2" from where?

Answer (score 1):

If the center of the flange on the floor is 13-1/2" from the wall where the tank goes and the new toilet is 10" or 12" then that is fine. There will just be a gap behind the toilet. If the toilet was set to 13-1/2" and the flange was at 10" or 12", then that would be a different story.